# Mercurial/Fig commands access denied

Tags: mercurial, fig

Unable to access any `hg` commands, getting following error:

```
abort: repository requires features unknown to this Mercurial: citc exp-remotefilelog-repo-req-1 fig narrowhg-experimental srcfs_manifestlog!
(see https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MissingRequirement for more information)
```

Tried to reinstall mercurial (v5.2.1) but issue is still persists.

Anyone has faced this issue?

Comment: At a guess I'd say you need to install the hg extensions that the repo requites.

Comment: Tried that too... not working...

Comment: Did you make sure those extensions were also enabled?

Comment: can you tell us what repo is this?

Comment: Got resolved the issue. There were `fig` permission errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo mule install fig
sudo mule update && sudo mule upgrade fig
```

these commands worked for me.